# Porque no me centra el label en el panel?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, objeto

lo que quiero hacer es añadir un label que es un contador, lo que pasa es que quiero centrarlo en el centro del panel independientemente de las medidas que tenga el panel siempre que este este en el centro, he probado en calcular de varias maneras en la posición Y me lo centra bien, pero en la X no, siempre me lo pone a la derecha del todo:

```
//Aquí recibo la posición del raton para ubicarlo en el form//
pnl.Location = new Point(xCentro- pnl.Width / 2, yCentro - pnl.Height / 2);
pnl.Height = 100;
pnl.Width = 100;
pnl.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
lb.Location = new Point((pnl.Width / 2) - (lb.Width / 2), (pnl.Height / 2) - (lb.Height / 2));
lb.Text = contador.ToString();
            
pnl.Controls.Add(lb);
frmPadre.Controls.Add(pnl);
```

Corrección: Si el tamaño del panel se reduce no se ve más el label, no se que probar más.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código, no tiene ningún error, tu `label`  se ubica correctamente al centro del contenedor `Panel` `pnl`, lo que no estas ubicando al centro del `label` es el texto que le agregas.
Para ello debes establecer de manera adecuada la propiedad `TextAlign`.

```
//Aquí recibo la posición del raton para ubicarlo en el form//
pnl.Location = new Point(xCentro- pnl.Width / 2, yCentro - pnl.Height / 2);
pnl.Height = 100;
pnl.Width = 100;
pnl.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
lb.Location = new Point((pnl.Width / 2) - (lb.Width / 2), (pnl.Height / 2) - (lb.Height / 2));

//Esta linea colocará el texto al centro vertical y horizontalmente del control label
lb.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

lb.Text = contador.ToString();
            
pnl.Controls.Add(lb);
frmPadre.Controls.Add(pnl);
```

Sobre el planteamiento final, en el que planteas que si se reduce el tamaño del `Panel` `pnl`, el `label` desaparece, te recomiendo que revises el tamaño (propiedad `Zize`) con que lo estas creando, pues presumo que lo que sucede en realidad, es que si reduces el tamaño del `pnl`, tu `label` se extiende fuera de los limites del `pnl` por lo que si el texto del `label` se alinea a la izquierda, entonces quedara fuera del panel y no será visible, pero el `label` y su texto están ahí, te recomiendo revisar el `Zize` del `label` y establecerlo siempre a un valor menor que el del `pnl`; otra opción es usar las propiedades `Dock` y/o `Anchor`

Comment: Muchas gracias ha funcionado, me estaba volviendo loco con ponerlo en medio, no había caído que se podía alinear el texto. Y revisare la propiedad "Zize" como me dices. Gracias!

Comment: @Wail Por nada amigo, estamos aquí para colaborar.